# Bootstrap datepicker pop-up not shown the highlighted current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap datepicker by using Bootstrap-datepicker API. When I click the button the calendar/datepicker pop-up shown but it didn't mark the current date as Blue font as shown in API examples.

I am using the below code:

```
   <body>
   <div class="input-group date col-md-5" id="datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
        <input class="form-control" size="56" type="text" value="" readonly>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
   </div>

    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    </script>
    </body>
```

The calendar/datepicker pop-up shown but the current date is not highlighted as blue as shown in API Examples and also the mouse cursor is not pointer.

Please help me regarding this issue

Comment: make sure you added the fonts for glyphicons. "glyphicon" class works if fonts are included

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you are using this : https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker  you have to give options when you initiate calendar,  such as

```
   $('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({ 
               todayHighlight: true
   });
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle. It will be helpful

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. The setting marks the date at the time of viewing, but not the currently selected date.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Here is  the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RaviRokkam/2w2h3rn8/9/)

Answer (score 1):

[Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io) depends on its own CSS for styling the calendar widget.

For quickly importing the dependence, you can pick a version from [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-datepicker) (make sure you pick a .css extension) and import into your HTML like this:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- ... -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the list of possible solutions as I was experiencing the same problem. The `today` class was not getting assigned to the current day using:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    'format': 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    'todayHighlight': true
});
```

The html in the example has a class of `date` only.

```
<div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="12-02-2012">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
       </div>
</div>
```

In my case, I was missing the `datepicker` class. Added that to the element and now everything is working properly.

Needs to be:

```
<div class="input-group date datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="12-02-2012">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add this attribute to your `datepicker` input element:

`today-highlight="true"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using reactive form then you can also set today's date as a value in your formGroup initiation like this

```
  myform = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    event_date: new FormControl(new Date(), [Validators.required]), //This is the change you need to mention into your form Group
  })
```